# Continue Checking Method

Tags: ios, xcode, methods

I have a method that starts my game (startGame).  I call it in `viewDidLoad` ([self startGame];).  The problem is, that the start game method checks to see if an object has moved before it starts the game.  The setup I have right now only calls the method once and doesn't check it again which means my game never starts.  Any ideas on how I can continue checking the method UNTIL the game starts, and then stop checking it?

Thanks.  Happy 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a few things you can do.. one of the easiest would be to use a `NSTimer`. so in your `viedDidLoad` method you could do:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkObjectMoved:) userInfo:NULL repeats:YES]; // check every 1 second
```

then you'd have:

```
- (void)checkObjectMoved:(NSTimer *)timer {
  if object has NOT moved return;

  [timer invalidate];
  [self startGame];
}
```

Comment: - (void)checkObjectMoved:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if(player.center.x != self.view.center.x || player.center.y != self.view.center.y)
    {
    [timer invalidate];
    [self startGame];
    }
}

Comment: like that? filler filler

Comment: It waits a second, and then starts even if I didn't move player

Comment: Also, Do you happen to know how I could reset the game after the person loses? Right now it removes everything and re-adds it which doesn't work with the start method (even the one I had before)

Comment: ahh hmm that's very dependent on how your game works. removing everything and re-adding it should, in theory, work.

Comment: the CheckObjectMoved doesn't wait for the object to move...it just waits a second and then starts...Should it be [timer validate]; or something like that?

Comment: no, [timer invalidate] is only when you want to stop a timer. looking at your code the game will start as soon as the player.center != view.center... that's the bit you want to look at.